# how to replace extract word

Tags: emacs, replace

all

I am new to emacs, I have a simple problem, when searching, emacs provides search by word, but when replace, how can I just replace the extract word, not a substring? I have searched on the internet, someone said to add `\bfoo\b` to match `foo` only, won't match `foos` but it doesn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For string-based search/replace, can run `query-replace-word` by typing: <kbd>C-u M-%</kbd>.

If you want regular expression search, then, indeed, you can enclose your regexp in either `\b` which matches word boundaries, or even `\<` and `\>` for beginning and end of word respectively. Make sure to use `M-x replace-regexp` in that case, not just `M-x query-replace`.

Comment: Thanks, Thomas, I should use 'M-x replace-regexp', it works for my case. previously I use 'M-x replace-string' by mistake